# Overload operator= for a class with shared_ptr with cycles in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, shared-ptr, operator-keyword, cycle

I have come across a problem where I need to overload operator= in C++. But when copying elements of right-hand size object to the left-hand side one, I encountered the problem. Say we have two classes,

```
class A {
public:
    A();

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> bs;

    A& operator =(const A& _rhs) {
        // How to assign bs so that there is no cycle
        // the newly created A contains new shared_ptr Bs
    }

};

class B {
public:
    B();

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> as;

    B& operator =(const B& _rhs) {
        // How to assign ..
    }
}
```

Is there a way to overcome this situation?

Comment: Who is supposed to own whom? This looks like a design problem.

Comment: Yes, properly design ownership.

Comment: Should `operator=` do a deep copy ?

Comment: There is no ownership between those classes. The reason they refer to each other is for the sake of effiency. As are megaliths and Bs are locations from Stonehenge game.(See https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora160.html for details) To quickly compute some properties of A, the A needs certains Bs and vice versa. Yes As and Bs holds the properties of the current game board.

Comment: If there is no ownership relationship between them, just use raw pointers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yup that overcomes the situation. But the reason I asked whether it is viable with smart pointers is that those pointers are also used in some other class, I thought using smart pointers would be the right choice, till I stuck..

Comment: @Jarod42 unfortunately

Comment: Without ownership, regular pointer or `weak_ptr` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Jarod42 I see. But couldn't think of how to do deep copy with weak_ptr?

Comment: I actually didn't provide to much detail. Actual owner of As and Bs is class Board, in that example I'm actually trying to do deep copy of Board. So do you think it is possible to initialize Board with initial As and Bs then transfer the properties of the RHS Board's As and Bs to the newly initialized one.

Comment: If you want deep copy then `shared_ptr` won’t help you... If the board is the owner, it might be simpler to have regular pointers in the above vectors `as` and `bs`. If you really need to have multiple owners, then `weak_ptr` would be appropriate.